# How to use SWITCH statement in PHP when checking if variables not empty?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have written IF statement for checking if variables are not empty:

```
  if ( !empty( $firstname )) {
    $data = array_merge( $data, array( 'first_name' => $firstname )); 
  }
  if ( !empty( $lastname )) {
    $data = array_merge( $data, array( 'last_name' => $lastname )); 
  }
  if ( !empty( $email )) {
    $data = array_merge( $data, array( 'email' => $email )); 
  }
  // and there are even more statements then these 3 ...
```

I think this is so DRY and tried to use SWITCH instead of IF:

```
switch( true ){
  case ( !empty( $firstname )):
    $data = array_merge( $data, array( 'first_name' => $firstname ));
  case ( !empty( $lastname )):
    $data = array_merge( $data, array( 'last_name' => $lastname ));
  case ( !empty( $email )):
    $data = array_merge( $data, array( 'email' => $email ));
```

Finally I get an array of all these 3 elements merged even if one of these variables is empty. What do i do wrong?

P.S. I can't do `IF(!empty(a) && !empty(b) && !empty(c))` because of need to check each condition separately.

Comment: Is `$firstname` an array?

Comment: Far as I know, all cases require breaks, per the manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: I think if you need to check each condition separately then the multiple if statments is correct over a switch.  A switch would be a substitute for a long `if/elseif/elseif.... `statement which has a single outcome, if you need to check every condition and then act accordingly for each one then (tedious as it may be) a your original collection of if's seems more appropriate

Comment: also, moving all those checks into a switch statement is no DRYer than the ifs, you're still writing them all out.  DRY is for Don't Repeat Yourself, this means don't do the same if statement twice, not don't have lots of if statements

Comment: Thank you @FunkFortyNiner, but then after first break SWITCH stop checking other conditions.

Comment: @Domaru that's the point of a switch statement

Comment: You could try a simple `compact` x `array_filter` solution, like the one I've given below!

Comment: OK, @jameson2012, I got. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy solution would be

```
$data = array_merge($data, array_filter(compact("firstname", "lastname", "email")));
```

Compact is a handy function that converts a listing of variable names into an array of its values. Array filter would remove all the empty elements, and lastly you can merge it with `$data`

Comment: Thank you! Very clever solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Just out of interest I tested your code as I was curious about the comment you make at the end to say that even if a variable is empty then it is still included in the switch.  I tested it out

```
    $firstname = '';//also tested with $firstname = null;
    $lastname = 'joe';
    $email = 'joe@null.com';
    $data = [];
    switch( true ){
      case ( !empty( $firstname )):
        $data = array_merge( $data, array( 'first_name' => $firstname ));
      case ( !empty( $lastname )):
        $data = array_merge( $data, array( 'last_name' => $lastname ));
      case ( !empty( $email )):
        $data = array_merge( $data, array( 'email' => $email ));
    }
    print_r($data);
```

The output is:

```
Array ( [last_name] => joe [email] => joe@null.com )
```

Which is what I would have expected - I'm only adding this as I think you might have variables you think are empty but aren't.  So before implementing the solution already posted, make sure you also check your variables are in the state you think they are

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop and test with not empty by using variable variables.

```
<?php
$firstname = 'Paul';
$email     = 'paul@example.com';

$data = ['age' => '34'];
foreach(['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'] as $name) {
    if(!empty($$name)) {
        $data[$name] = $$name;
    }
}

var_export($data);
```

Output:

```
array (
'age' => '34',
'firstname' => 'Paul',
'email' => 'paul@example.com',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `compact` function with `array_filter` was a good enough approach. I'm just sharing an alternative of using ternary operator for your problem's solution.

```
$data = !empty($firstname) ? array_merge( $data , [ 'firstname' => $firstname] ) : $data;
$data = !empty($lastname)  ? array_merge( $data , [ 'lastname' => $lastname]  ) : $data;
$data = !empty($email)  ? array_merge( $data , [ 'email' => $email] ) : $data;
```